# How to get the element number/index between siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can you get the child number of the selected element, e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li>First child</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li id="selected">Third child</li>
    <li>Fourth child</li>
</ul>
```

Using something like this:

```
$('#selected').childNumber();
```

That should return "3" for it's parent wrap, regarding the child number.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use [**`.index()`**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for this.

```
var selectedIndex = $("#selected").index() + 1;
```

Since you have given an id for the li there is no need for the element selector with ul. You can directly use the id selector for the li element.

Comment: Simple and effective, thanks. :)

Comment: its always better to use the type selector too to improve the search speeds, $("li#selected") should be quicker than $("#selected").

Comment: @shortstick not with id-selectors ('#') which uses native function  getElementByID which is faster.