# Change content div when hover link

Tags: jquery, css, hover

For a business website I'm trying to achieve the following:
- A div with testimonials from clients.
- A list with logos from those clients.

When the user hovers over a logo, the correct testimonial should be displayed in the div.

I've got the following markup:

```
<div id="testimonial-container"><div class="testimonial">Here comes a testimonial</div>
    <div class="testimonial">Here comes another testimonial</div>
    <div class="testimonial">And another one</div>
    <ul class="testimonial-logos">
       <li><a><img src="logo-1.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a><img src="logo-2.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a><img src="logo-3.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The hover effect will be done with CSS (opacity:0, and 1), so it isn't really a slider.

To add a class to the active testimonial, I use this code:

```
jQuery('#testimonial-container .testimonial-logos a').hover(function(){
    jQuery('#testimonial-container .testimonial, #testimonial-container .testimonial-logos a').addClass('active');
});
```

Any ideas how to switch the testimonials in the div? Thanks in advance!

Comment: in the second parameter to the `hover` function u could write ur alternative code right?

Comment: how would you know which testimonials would a certain logo target? Each testimonial should have at least a unique id so you can target them exactly.

Comment: @DexterHuinda - You don't need ids _assuming_ you can rely on the logos being in the same order as the testimonials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the testimonials are in the same order as the corresponding logos then something like this will work (place within a document ready handler or in a script block at the end of the body):

```
var $container = $("#testimonial-container"),
    $testimonials = $(".testimonial", $container).hide();

$(".testimonial-logos li", $container).hover(function() {
    $testimonials.eq( $(this).addClass("active").index() ).show();
}, function() {
    $testimonials.eq( $(this).removeClass("active").index() ).hide();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/YG5aV/3

This caches a jQuery object containing the testimonial divs, and immediately hides them all. Then within the hover handler, on mouse *enter* it shows the one corresponding to the logo being hovered and on mouse *leave* it hides it again.

UPDATE: If the intention is to do something only on mouse enter rather than mouse enter *and* leave then I'd suggest `.mouseenter()` rather than `.hover()` because the latter is a shortcut for assigning both an enter handler and a leave hander. The following does what you describe in the comment - note the `.eq(0).mouseenter()` on the end, which triggers the mouseenter for the first li element so that it will be the active one to start with.

```
var $container = $("#testimonial-container"),
    $testimonials = $(".testimonial", $container).hide(),
    $prev;

$(".testimonial-logos li", $container).mouseenter(function() {
    if ($prev)
       $testimonials.eq( $prev.removeClass("active").index() ).hide();
    $testimonials.eq( ($prev = $(this).addClass("active")).index() ).show();
}).eq(0).mouseenter();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YG5aV/4/

Comment: The code works perfect. Thanks! Is it possible to keep one testimonial displayed by default? And keep the current testimonial displayed, even when the user doesn't hover?

Comment: Very last question: The active <li> gets a class "active". How can I add the same class to the active testimonial div?

Comment: `$testimonials.eq( ($prev = $(this).addClass("active")).index() ).show().addClass("active");` (Just chain an `.addClass("active")` call after the existing `.show()`. Do the same thing to chain a `.removeClass("active")` call after the existing `.hide()`.)

Answer (score 1):

I would give each of your testimonals an ID for example `<div class"testimonial" id="logo-1.jpg">` then on the mouse over you logo it can find the correct testimonial and display it

Comment: Ah, I was thinking about that too. So I will give them a unique ID. Thanks. But the number of logos will vary. What is the best option to find the correct testimonial?

Comment: Will there always be one logo per testimonial, or is it possible for two logos to point at the same testimonial

Comment: Also, how are these being added, are you just creating the controls you need or are you making them dynamically from a database or something?

Comment: No, there will only be one logo per testimonial. But sometimes there will be 5 logos and testimonials displayed, and sometimes 2 or 3, etc. The total number will vary, depending of the number of clients.

Comment: The logos and testimonials will be added from a database (WordPress).

Comment: Thats fine, so each of your logos has the mouse over event, if you want to do this more cleanly you could add a custom attribute such as data-testimonialId=1 then on mouse over get that attribute, find element by ID of what ever that attribute contains. On your testimonial divs (which I assume are all hidden) have the correct IDs and then you can show that Div in a popup or however your doing it. So when you create all the controls from your database, you need to apply the data-testimonialId attribute on the logo, and the ID on the Testimonial divs. Does that make sense?

Comment: just give both the logo and testimonial an unique id where they can meet and find each other, e.g. `<div class="testimonial" id="testimonial-id1">` and your logo like `<img rel="testimonial-id1">`, then you can get the `rel` attr of the logo to target the `div`.

Comment: Thanks a lot theedam for the extended explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .index() and .eq() selectors to determine which link you hovered.

```
$('#testimonial-container .testimonial-logos a').hover(function(){
    var index = $('#testimonial-container .testimonial-logos a').index(this);
    $('#testimonial-container .testimonial, #testimonial-container .testimonial-logos a').removeClass('active');
    $('#testimonial-container .testimonial, #testimonial-container .testimonial-logos a').eq(index).addClass('active');
});
```

jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/8EgB4/

Answer (score 0):

You could get the ordinal of the hovered child using [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654028/getting-the-element-number-in-jquery) and then access the related testimonial using the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).  The nth-child selector uses an ordinal, so you'd need to add 1 to the index value to get the correct testimonial.  You would also need to make sure that you list your logos and testimonials in the same order.