# Get element's child cardinal number based on class?

Tags: jquery

How do I get the li element with class "selected" position inside it's container?

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="selected"></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

In this case it should return 2 as it's the second li inside it's container.

Comment: I don't think `ul` can have a `div` as its direct child

Comment: I removed it to avoid confusion. But I would like it to ignore extra elements inside the ul.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = $('li.selected');
$('ul li').index(elem);
```

This will return 1, as the elements index starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".selected").index();
```

[Check out](http://api.jquery.com/index/) the `.index(...)` jQuery function.

Note that the index function returns the node's position starting from zero, not from one, so the first element would be "in the zero index."

Answer (score 0):

You may read this: [How to get the element number/index between siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654028/getting-the-element-number-in-jquery)

`var selectedIndex = $("#selected").index() + 1;`

`var selectedIndex = $(".selected").index() + 1;` (for you)

That was the accepted answer and it is good also for your question.

Also read [Index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li class="selected"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>​
```

**JS**

```
var selectedIndex=$("ul li.selected").index()+1; 
alert(selectedIndex); // outputs 2
```

Basically first index is `0` and second index is`1`, so `+1` is being used according to your question two get the second index as `2` instead of `1`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/QrtPG/2/).