# jQuery - How to find an index of an ID within another container DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web

I thought to use **`.index`** but it don't seem to work!

```
<div id="main">
       <div id="one"> 
               <div class="red"> ... </div>
       </div> 
       <div id="two"> 
               <div class="green"> ... </div>
       </div> 
       <div id="three"> 
               <div class="blue"> ... </div>
       </div> 
</div>
```

So I tried:

```
var isDivThere = $("main").index("#two") != -1;
```

but as mentioned, no go...

How can I simply look up a div inside div #main?

Comment: `var isDivThere = $('#main', '#two').length;`

Comment: Do you want to get the *index* of the element or test whether it exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the element number/index between siblings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654028/how-to-get-the-element-number-index-between-siblings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#main > div").index($("#two"))

var isDivThere =  $("#main > div").index($("#two")) != -1;
```

Note: `>` is for filter only first level div's. So my solution will not work if you want to check the index of nested divs.

Answer (score 2):

To check for existence, you can simply do this:

```
var isDivThere = !!$('#two').length;
```

If `#two` must exist inside `#main`:

```
var isDivThere = !!$('#main').find('#two').length;
```

If `#two` must be a child of `#main`:

```
var isDivThere = !!$('#main').children('#two').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

To know the index of an element within its container just invoke `index` over the element id your are looking for:

```
var isDivThere = $("#two").index();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NGhL7/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the # symbol for selecting by id. Working fiddle here:

```
$("#yourId");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnFh5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use find() function of jquery,

```
  $("#main").find("#two");
```

Answer (score 0):

$Because the ID is unique within the all body this is enough to do what you do:

```
var isDivThere =  !!$$("#two").length;
```

you will never find another element with an ID="two" so you have no need to identify that telling that is insode the main div