# get position of .length jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using `$('.gallery img').click` to call a function and using `.length` to get a value to us in a comparison, I need to get the position of img in the div. so the .gallery div is like an array and the img in it is a number "0 to 9" so I click the third img and get 2 or the fifth one and get 4.

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML, and the function you mention.

Comment: Sounds like a very similar question to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654028/how-to-get-the-element-number-index-between-siblings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `index` method for getting the index of the clicked image element in a jQuery collection:

```
var $img = $('.gallery img').on('click', function() {
    var i = $img.index(this);
});
```

If the image wrapper has only image children you can can also use the `index` method without passing the element:

```
var i = $(this).index();
```

Comment: This worked, the way I implemented it was like so "gal_id = $('.gallery img').index(this);"